# How to close the alert dialog explicitly?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

In my activity, I am loading some eight fragments, from the 8th fragment showing some alert dialog.After that session getting expired, so redirected them to the first fragment without user interaction.During that time alert dialog not getting closed which created from 8 fragments.

Comment: please provide relevant code.....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs i haven't tried any code because no idea of do this as an explicit.

Answer (score 0):

If you using alert dialog like that:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
```

you need to keep the dialog instance which returns from the show method and call dismiss from that instance.

```
 AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();

 //Use this anywhere to close
 dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the onPause() of your 8th Fragment you should hide the AlertDialog.

```
class XYZ extends Fragment{ 
    //Keep the reference to AlertDialog as a member variable in your Fragment 
    AlertDialog mDialog;
    //other member declarations ...

  @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // check if dialog is not null and is already showing 
        if(mDialog !=null && mDialog.isHowing())
            mDialog.hide();   
        super.onPause();
}
```

Note : If the viewpager removes 8th fragment from memory and some action that you perform in your dialog references your 8th fragment then it would cause null pointer exception.